# How to implement touch listener fot items of listview?

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to implement `OnTouchListener` for items of `ListView`! I tried 
`listview.getChildAt(pos).setOnTouchListener` But app got error and stopped. I know that `getChildAt()` doesn't return item view properly.

Is there another way to perform it?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? On touch event ?

Comment: yes....................

Comment: See my answer. I should add you need to make sure your listview has the id android:id/list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by extending ListActivity or ListFragment and then overriding OnListItemClick in those classes.

Otherwise you could set it in your adapter for each view.

Edit:

In order to have something click able in your list item you have to set its on click listener in your list adapter.

Then in your layout with you list view add this lines to your list view xml:

android:click able=true
android:descendantfocusability="beforeDefendants"

Then in the XML for your list row add these lines for whatever you want to.be cliclable:

android:focusable ="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

Comment: Why cant you change your code? Do neither of the suggestions above satisfy what you're trying to do?

Comment: I want to change background image of items when touched!

Comment: So you want to add an ontouchlistener for a button or something within 1 row of your listview?